# What is this grey-white mold/fungus below my tree?

Tags: plant-health, tree-care, fungus, mold

I’m trying to grow a tree and I keep finding this fungus in the soil (photo attached). My plant isn’t doing well (it is a potted evergreen and is growing inside). I give my plant a good watering once-twice a week, depending on how dry the soil is. Is this fungus the reason why my plant is dying? How can I get rid of it? I dig some out every day, when I get up in the morning and when I go to sleep at night. I’m not sure what else to do or if this fungus is harmful. [image]

Comment: Most plants have a cooperative relationship with various sorts of fungus. If you're "digging some out every day" you might be the primary cause of your plant being unhappy. Daily root disturbance is not well-tolerated in general.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to believe that this fungus is causing harm to your plant, and there's really no way to get rid of it without killing your plant. The soil appears to have a lot of coarse organic matter, which I would guess the fungus is living off of. Fungi are naturally present in almost all soils, decomposing organic matter and releasing nutrients that plants can use in the process.

The fuzzy aerial growth form may be a sign that you are watering too frequently or that your pot has poor drainage, which could harm your plant. Check what is recommended for your specific plant in terms of watering.